# How to set the color of caret blinking cursor in QLineEdit

Tags: qt, cursor, qt5, qlineedit

How to set the color of caret blinking cursor in QLineEdit?
I have a question, which is how to change the color  of caret blinking cursor in QLineEdit.

Answer (score 3):

## How text input controls work in Qt

All Qt text input widgets actually use an internal "widget text control" (see `qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp` and `qwidgetlinecontrol_p.h` in the [official sources](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets)), which is a private QObject that implements all aspects related to the text of their related widgets (such as key presses, keyboard navigation, text appearance, cursor display, etc.) and is eventually delegated for actual text painting.

Complex text widgets such as QPlainTextEdit provide access to many important aspects of such controls through public functions (eventually using QTextDocument APIs internally), but basic widgets such as QLineEdit don't, making it impossible to specifically change the appearance of aspects such as the text cursor (normally known as the [*caret*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface))).

Internally, when `paintEvent()` of QLineEdit is called (see the [sources](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp#n1973)), after making some proper computation about the text positioning (including offset caused by text larger than the line edit), it finally calls a `draw()` function of the above control, which includes the cursor (assuming it's being shown an not in the "off" state of its blinking).

This clearly means that there is no practical nor immediate way to change the appearance of the text cursor using public functions.

## A possible alternative

A viable solution would be made of two elements:

- a custom QLineEdit subclass that implements some custom properties, telling whether it has to show a custom caret, and eventually draw it when needed;
- a QProxyStyle subclass that overrides `pixelMetric()`, possibly returning `0` if the metric is a `PM_TextCursorWidth`, in order to avoid the default drawing;

The result of the QProxyStyle implementation above is that no caret is being shown at all (since it has no width), allowing us to eventually draw our custom caret in place of it.

Note that `pixelMetric()` has only one mandatory argument (the metric), and the call in the QLineEdit `paintEvent()` did *not* include a related QStyleOption for Qt <= [5.13](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp?h=5.13#n2055), possibly making it almost impossible to define custom behavior between any QLineEdit.
Since [5.14](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp?h=5.14#n2080), the option argument is provided, so we can create a QLineEdit subclass with custom properties that allows the style to alter the returned cursor width based on it, because it can be retrieved by using the QStyleOption `styleObject` (previously set with [`initFrom()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoption.html#initFrom) in the default `paintEvent()`).

### Custom caret implementation

The line edit subclass implements 3 custom properties:

- `caretSize`: the width of the "cursor"; the default is `-1`, meaning that the widget should follow the default behavior; `0` means no caret display at all;
- `caretColor`: the QColor of the cursor; it defaults to `Qt::black`, if it's explicitly set to a valid color and the `caretSize` is `<=0`, it automatically changes it to `1` in order to make it visible and ignore the default one;
- `customCaret`: a *read-only* property only based on the above properties: it just tells the widget if it has to follow the default behavior or not, making it also visible to the proxy style; if the size is less than 0, the *proxy* tell the style to paint the default caret, otherwise nothing will be shown in that phase; if the size is greater than 0, and the color is valid, the rest of the `paintEvent` override will draw the custom caret;

### The blinking cursor

Since the cursor blinking is handled internally (through private properties such as `m_blinkStatus` defined in `qwidgetlinecontrol_p.h`), we need to override that too.

Luckily, we can just *assume* the blinking by using the [`QStyleHint.cursorFlashTime`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylehints.html#cursorFlashTime-prop) property and considering the standard behavior: always show the caret (and start the blinking) whenever the widget is focused or any key is pressed.
Note that we should also consider other aspects (like the `readOnly` property), but I'll leave all that out for the purpose of simplicity.

Finally, the painting of the custom caret requires some ingenuity.
While the internal text control is theoretically reachable and provides some public functions (using `findChildren()` upon initialization and through the QMetaObject interface), there is no immediate way to know the actual cursor position.

Still, we can make an educated guess: the [`QLineEdit::cursorRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#cursorRect) normally returns a (wide) rectangle that has the caret in its center, so we can *assume* the caret position by adding the half of the rectangle width to its `x` (using `QRect.center().x()` is probably unreliable). The vertical position is based on the rectangle `y` and the widget's font metrics `height()`.

We only need to create a QPainter and draw the caret as a rectangle, considering the above properties.

## Code example

Unfortunately, I cannot really write in C++, but I crafted a reproducible example in PyQt that can be probably and easily ported in C++.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class CustomCaretStyle(QProxyStyle):
    def pixelMetric(self, pm, opt=None, widget=None):
        if (
            pm == QStyle.PM_TextCursorWidth and opt
            and isinstance(opt.styleObject, CustomCaretLineEdit)
            and opt.styleObject.property('customCaret')
        ):
            return 0
        return super().pixelMetric(pm, opt, widget)


class CustomCaretLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    _caretSize = -1
    _caretColor = QColor() # invalid color
    _cursorVisible = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setStyle(CustomCaretStyle())
        self._blinkTimer = QTimer(self, timeout=self._toggleCursor, 
            interval=QApplication.styleHints().cursorFlashTime() // 2)

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def caretSize(self):
        return self._caretSize

    @caretSize.setter
    def caretSize(self, size):
        if size < 0:
            size = -1
        if self._caretSize != size:
            self._caretSize = size
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(QColor)
    def caretColor(self):
        return self._caretColor

    @caretColor.setter
    def caretColor(self, color):
        if self._caretColor != color:
            self._caretColor = color
            if color.isValid() and self._caretSize < 1:
                self._caretSize = 1
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(bool)
    def customCaret(self):
        return self._caretSize >= 0 or self._caretColor.isValid()

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        super().focusInEvent(event)
        self._startBlink()

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        super().focusOutEvent(event)
        self._stopBlink()

    def _startBlink(self):
        self._cursorVisible = True
        self._blinkTimer.start()

    def _stopBlink(self):
        self._cursorVisible = False
        self._blinkTimer.stop()

    def _toggleCursor(self):
        self._cursorVisible = not self._cursorVisible

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        self._startBlink()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if not self.customCaret or not self._cursorVisible:
            return
        qp = QPainter(self)
        fullRect = self.cursorRect()
        x = fullRect.x() + round(fullRect.width() // 2) + 1
        cr = QRect(
            x, fullRect.y(), 
            max(1, self._caretSize), self.fontMetrics().height())
        qp.fillRect(cr, 
            self._caretColor if self._caretColor.isValid()
                else self.palette().text())


app = QApplication([])

standard = CustomCaretLineEdit('hello') # default caret
custom = CustomCaretLineEdit('world', caretColor=QColor('red'), caretSize=2)

test = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(test)
layout.addWidget(standard)
layout.addWidget(custom)

test.show()
app.exec()
```

Note that:

- PyQt allows setting existing QObject properties as undefined keyword arguments; as far as I know, C++ doesn't allow that, so the `caretColor` property should be set afterwards;
- the above should technically work even for QLineEdits that are affected by style sheets (since the `pixelMetric` call doesn't include the `widget` argument); it is still possible that future versions of Qt eventually change that behavior, making all the above completely invalid, because the QStyle function calls to the QStyleSheetStyle do not call the base style function if the `widget` is provided;
- the blinking timer is only based on the current style upon initialization; this means that the timer interval should be updated in case the style of the widget or the overall application is changed at runtime *after* that point: QLineEdit actually uses QBasicTimer to do so, which makes things a bit simpler to manage, but require a more extended implementation of that, I didn't use that in the above code to avoid unnecessary complexity;
- I've only tested the above with a few standard fonts and just few custom sizes; the caret geometry is based on some font metrics assumptions and may depend on various aspects (other fonts or OS/Qt versions may give different behavior); feel free to comment about your tests and their results;

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution I came up with using QLineEdit. It uses the paintEvent to generate a custom caret. I have thought about this for about 2 years and, after stumbling on this thread, decided to try to find a solution.

My solution makes an assumption that you're assigning a font to the field. In this widget, I am using the Hasklig Nerd Font. [Download here](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.2.2/Hasklig.zip).

Maybe there is a less convoluted way to go about this, but this works for me. If you change the font, you may need to re-evaluate some of the math to get the caret step feeling good.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QFont, QFontMetricsF
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QCommonStyle, QStyle, QStyleOption


_WIDGET_HEIGHT: int = 24


class CaretStyle(QCommonStyle):

    def __init__(self, width: int = None):
        """
        This allows us to set the width of the default widget input caret.

        Args:
            width (int): The width of the input caret in pixels.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self._width = 5 if width is None else width

    def pixelMetric(self, pixel_metric: QStyle, option: QStyleOption = None, widget: QWidget = None):
        if pixel_metric == QStyle.PM_TextCursorWidth:
            return self._width
        else:
            return QCommonStyle.pixelMetric(self, pixel_metric, option, widget)


def remap_value(value: float, old: tuple, new: tuple) -> float:
    """Range remaps a value using old and new min/max."""
    old_min, old_max = old
    new_min, new_max = new
    return (new_max - new_min) * (value - old_min) / (old_max - old_min) + new_min


class StringInput(QLineEdit):
    _caret_pos_x: float = 0.0
    _caret_pos_y: float = 1 + _WIDGET_HEIGHT * 0.2
    _font_metric: QFontMetricsF = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        QLineEdit with custom input field caret.
        """
        super().__init__(parent=kwargs.get("parent", None))
        self.setObjectName("ParmInput")

        self.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

        # hide the default caret by scaling it to 0
        self.setStyle(CaretStyle(width=0))

        # accessing font details is important for accurate
        # caret positioning
        font = QFont("Hasklug NF", 9, QFont.Thin)
        font.setHintingPreference(QFont.HintingPreference.PreferNoHinting)
        self._font_metric = QFontMetricsF(font)
        self.setFont(font)

        # align the text within the field
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # we need this so we can update the caret in the field as the user
        # does stuff.
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self._update_caret_pos_x)

    def _update_caret_pos_x_x(self):
        """Calculate the position of the caret based on cursor position."""
        text: str = self.text()
        step: float = self._font_metric.averageCharWidth() - 1

        # if the field is empty set the character to teh step value.
        # this puts the caret where the first char would be. this also
        # prevents divide by 0 if no text is in the field.
        if len(text) < 1:
            self._caret_pos_x = step
            return

        cursor_pos: int = self.cursorPosition()
        text_width: int = self._font_metric.width(text)
        char_count: len(text)

        # remap the cursor position based on the current text in the field.
        self._caret_pos_x = remap_value(cursor_pos, 0, 1, 0, text_width) / char_count + step

    def get_caret_pos_x(self) -> float:
        """Queries the current position of the caret."""
        return self._caret_pos_x

    def focusInEvent(self, event) -> None:
        """We update the caret position upon focus, based on where the user clicked."""
        self._update_caret_pos_x()

    def focusOutEvent(self, event) -> None:
        """Clear the current text selection if the field loses focus."""
        self.setSelection(0, 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """This creates a custom caret for the input field."""
        super().paintEvent(event)

        # easy out if the widget doesnt have focus
        if not self.hasFocus():
            return

        width: float = 2.0
        height: float = _WIDGET_HEIGHT/1.5

        painter: QPainter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        caret = QRect(self.get_caret_pos_x(), self._caret_pos_y, width, height)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(231, 167, 38, 150))
        painter.drawRect(caret)

        painter.end()
```

Comment: Sorry but this solution has many issues. While the concept may be acceptable, lots of problems raise, most importantly: 1. there is no cursor blinking; 2. you *never* call the base implementation of `focusInEvent` and `focusOutEvent`; 3. `char_count` is never set as a result, only as a type; 4. the call to `remap_value` has wrong arguments. In any case, your code is not runnable (mostly due to points 3 and 4 above), so, for future reference (for SO, but also for your own purposes), before focusing so much on unnecessary type hinting, ensure that your code actually works.

Comment: i mean, it works for me :shrug: sorry it is so problematic for you.